# Remove all 'b' tags and their contents from an html script

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was using beautiful soup and playing around with the Shrek script to get used to it when I wanted to try and get rid of all the b tags and their contents and leave only the remaining text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = "https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Shrek.html"
ua = UserAgent(verify_ssl=False)
headers = {'User-Agent': 'ua.chrome'}


def get_script():
    script_text = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(script_text.text, 'html.parser')
    script = soup.find('td', class_='scrtext')
    tag = script.find_all('b')
    if tag is None:
        pass
    else:
        tag.clear()

    print(tag)

get_script()
```

This is the code I used

If you were to comment out the if and else statements and run the code, id shows all the b tags and their contents, and if you were to uncomment and run it, it returns `[]`. So the tags *are* getting deleted and removed. Problem is, when I use `print(script)` instead of `print(tag)` it just returns the script normally without removing any of the b tags or their contents, even though they get removed.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What exactly r u trying to scrape from the website?

Comment: The script text without the <b> tags and their contents

Comment: Ok...So the text within it?

Comment: I answered myself so you can see what I was talking about

Answer (score 1):

To remove the `<b>` tags you should use `.extract()` like this:

```
for b in soup.find_all('b'):
  b.extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm all you had to do was

```
 for b in tag:
        b.clear()
        b.decompose()
```

This removes all the b tags and their contents while leaving the rest of the script untouched, which is what I wanted.